# Started using App on facebook?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook

Now, I see many apps that will say "started using [Name of App] "Is that simply a call to StreamPublish or is there a new function call to achieve this?

I am currently using facebook to allow people to log in with their facebook accounts similar to turntable.fm and then going to my webpage. How do I make it so that other friends can see that they started to use the application, I have not been able to find this anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

There is a setting on your application for "social discovery".  Enable it and those posts will show up.

[image]

Comment: do you need to have the write to wall permission or just this will do it?

Answer (score 1):

sorry, this is not an answer but clarification of the questions and answers (I don't seem to have enough points to be able to comment)

Firstly I'd like to say that if you are developing a Facebook app this would seem to be a very important question as it would have a huge impact on the virality of your app. It would mean that every single registered user is potentially advertising your app to each of their friends. Without out this happening your only options for viral spread through facebook are:

- asking for 'publish_stream' permission and using the 'Post to wall' API call. Asking for this may deter many users from using your app in the first place.
- User initiated sharing (like button, post to wall). Unless your app was amazingly awesome you'd be lucky to get a 5% rate with this (as opposed to the 100% rate you'd get with the mysterious 'started using' feed post)

I created a fake account for testing, created a facebook app (as a webpage, not as a facebook app/iframe), made sure social discovery was enabled, but I could not see any activity on my ticker or my feed. However, I did learn that there is a thing called the 'canvas ticker' which is completely separate from the 'main' ticker and can be seen when you use any facebook iframed-app. A notice did appear in the 'canvas ticker' but it said 'a is using b' not 'a started using b'. Getting a message on the 'canvas ticker' is not nearly as significant as getting a 'main ticker' or news feed post as relatively few people use 'facebook iframe apps'. I thought that this is what I must have remembered seeing (not seeing 'started using' in my news feed or main ticker), so I gave up worrying about it.

However, recently I started using Graph API Explorer http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ and a 'started using' post appeared in my alter-ego's news feed. That is exactly what I remember seeing with other apps ('started using' rather than 'is using') but it seems to be quite a rare occurance. I'm not sure if anything appeared in my alter-ego's main ticker.

Now I am really confused. This feels alot like figuring out how google's pagerank algorithm works.

update:

this link has proved quite useful: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/410

I think 'started playing' only applies if you app is set to having the 'games' category. Apparently these 'started playing' stories only show on the newsfeeds of people who have already started playing the game. So they can't really be of much use to gaining new users (as only user who are already using the app see it). However, the blog post states,

> "By showing fewer but more impactful News Feed stories based on
>   friends’ activity and social context, we hope to drive new user growth
>   for games. For example, instead of the typical story saying that
>   someone just bought a new item, it could say “Dave, Jonny and 3 other
>   friends” just started playing a game."

I am really confused by this. How can the 'started playing' story possibly 'drive new user growth' if they only appear to people who are already playing??

The 'x started using Graph API Explorer' seems to be a really odd one. I think because it's an app made by Facebook it has special priority and that's why it showed as a story in all of my friends's newsfeed. I've been installing  a lot of non-game apps to see if the 'started using' story appears but I could not find one that did. I'm now not sure if I ever remember seeing a 'started using' story. I installed games such as Farmville and Sims Social and yes i did see a 'started playing' story on my alter ego's newsfeed.

Why is that incredibly hard to find blog post above not part of the official documentation? And why doesn't the blog post explain exactly how things work with good and thorough examples instead of being really vague. I think every app should have an equal chance for viral growth without having to spend hours conducting psuedo scientific experiments with fake user accounts just to figure out how things works because the documentation is poor. I'm sure players like Zynga have the resources to figure out facebook inside and out but this is getting really frustrating as a sole developer.

This is why I'm hoping for a day when the prominent social network's code is open source. Nothing beats being able to directly read the source code when documenation is poor. That is one of the great things about open source.

Answer (score 0):

Hey this is a common question I hear from my clients whom I write FB apps for.
It's called the FB User Discovery Story and it's automatic.  Facebook eventually enables it for applications.  There's nothing you can do to make sure it's displayed and it's visibility is effected by the evoking users privacy settings as well as the receiving users settings.

Also, note that it does not require your application being in the app directory.
The new facebook application interface allows you toggle the feature on and off but it still relies on the users settings as well.