# Publish on user wall and user's friends walls - marketing my app

Tags: facebook, publish, facebook-wall

My app requires publish_stream. When a user accesses my app first time, I want to publish "Username has been started using My Awesome App + icon":

- on his wall
- on his friend's wall: is a limited number? Can I select his friends with the biggest number of friends?
- I do not want to require another confirmation for that (for future another postings I will ask user to confirm Publish)

Is it possible to do that and is it ok regarding policy?

Comment: see this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494048/started-using-app-on-facebook

Answer (score 0):

> on his wall

Thats okay, but you should use a confirmation dialog, or else you'll get flagged as spam a lot and get rate-limited, etc. Good applications that have value typically don't post on walls unless the user knows about it.

> on his friend's wall: is a limited number? can i select his friends
>   with the biggest number of friends?

that is spam and strictly forbidden. You'll get shut down real quick. Unless an action pertains to a friend (like sending them something or interacting in some way), you should not write on their wall.